# Azure Bot Framework fails to find nodejs module in azure

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service

I just deployed a azure bot (qna). When I try to send a message to it I get this error:

```
2017-05-26T04:34:12.078 Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: Error: Cannot find module 'botbuilder'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\index.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3).
```

I have not touched the presupplied code, so I'm not sure what's going on. Can someone from MSFT help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please add more tags, to enhance the visibility of your question in another related topics, for example 'nodejs', 'azure bot framework', etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Azure Bot Service v1 bug where Webchat is immediately available even if npm install has not completed, causing "Cannot find module 'botbuilder'" messages.  This will not affect the functioning of your bot. We are actively working to fix the issue.